# How can I compare two lists inside Editor script to make a for loop only one time each time the lists are not the same size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(DialogueTrigger))]
public class DialogueTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _dialogues;
    private SerializedProperty _conversations;
    private SerializedProperty old_Conversations;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
        old_Conversations.arraySize = _conversations.arraySize;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        //base.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        _conversations.arraySize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Conversations Size", _conversations.arraySize);

        if (old_Conversations.arraySize != _conversations.arraySize)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _conversations.arraySize; x++)
            {
                var conversation = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(x);

                var Id = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("conversationName");
                EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(Id);

                _dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                _dialogues.arraySize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Dialogues size", _dialogues.arraySize);

                for (int i = 0; i < _dialogues.arraySize; i++)
                {
                    var dialogue = _dialogues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
                    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(dialogue, new GUIContent("Dialogue " + i), true);
                }
            }
        }

        old_Conversations.arraySize = _conversations.arraySize;

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

Everything inside the OnInspectorGUI is call over and over again very fast.
So it's doing the loops nonstop.

I added a old copy of the _conversations:

```
private SerializedProperty old_Conversations;
```

I tried first time to assign it to the original _conversations inside the OnEnable:

```
old_Conversations.arraySize = _conversations.arraySize;
```

But I used a break point and the OnEnable never called.

Then before the loops I'm doing the check:

```
if (old_Conversations.arraySize != _conversations.arraySize)
```

In the bottom I'm making both equal again.

But it's not working. When changing the size of the _conversations it's all the time change it back to 1 and does nothing after it.

My main goal is somehow to call the loops only once each time the size changed.
It's working good if the size is 1 or 5 or 10 but if I change the size to 100 everything get slow almost freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeginChangeCheck / EndChangeCheck to detect the modification.

```
EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

_conversations.arraySize = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Conversations Size", _conversations.arraySize);

if(EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck()) {
     for ...
}
```

---

Page view

```
page = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Page", page);
int index = page * countPerPage;

for(int x = index; i < Mathf.Min(_conversations.arraySize, index + countPerPage); ++i)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's not working. It's not showing any of the EditorGUILayout fields. The problem is that the onInspectorGui have to be called all the time to make the EditorGUILayout to work but in the other hand if you loop over too many items it will make everything too slow.

Comment: _My main goal is somehow to call the loops only once each time the size changed_, that's what you said in your question and now the loop is called only if the size changed. So if you say this is not working, then the question has a mistake.

Comment: The problem in my opinion is that you have to call an EditorGUILayout method in every call of onGUI or onInspectorGUI if you want it to show up in the editor. So if it is laggy with so many items you have to make a workaround. My idea would be to use some sort of pagination.

Comment: If you don't want to show every elements in the array (but a part of them), then you don't need to do for loop through all of them. Instead `for(x = 0; x < _conversations.arraySize;` with `for(x = index; x < index + count;`, then make another `IntField` to change index value. Or like normal array in the inspector use `EditorGUI.Foldout` to toggle the visibility.

Comment: @shingo I tried to use your second solution with the Page. This is my code now can you look at it please in the link ? https://pastebin.com/gmc50HRZ I'm not sure if I'm using right with the page and countPerPage. I didn't test it yet since I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to save just the array size of the old conversations in an integer and not saving a second array. But there is a chance, that this wont work because i think the onInspectorGui code has to be executed in every call(But not sure about that).